# Netlogo, changing turtle's behavior by tick

Tags: netlogo

I want to change turtle's behavior.

first 6 ticks, turtles using foraging map to move. 
after foraging, turtles using resting map to rest in 6 ticks.

I tried to use count-down, but it failed it.

### this is the code I used

```
 to go

    move-turtles
    tick
    if ticks >= 4320
    [stop]
  end

  to move-turtles

    ask turtles 
  [
    foraging
    resting
  ]

  end





  to foraging

    uphill food
    if food >= [food] of one-of neighbors
        [move-to one-of neighbors]

    set count-down count-down - 1
    set label count-down
    set label-color red
    if count-down = 0
    [resting
      set label "6"
      reset-count-down
    ]

  end

  to resting

    uphill rplace
    if rplace >= [rplace] of one-of neighbors
    [move-to one-of neighbors]
       set count-down count-down - 1
    set label count-down
    set label-color blue
    if count-down = 0
    [foraging
      set label "6"
      reset-count-down
    ]
  end

  to reset-count-down

    set count-down 6

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a turtle attribute that tracks what state a turtle is in.  For example, you could add a `resting?` attribute, which you set to `true` when the foraging count down hits `0`, and set to `false` when the resting countdown hits `0`.  You will then condition behavior (foraging or resting) on this attribute.

Btw, usually you should name command procedures with a verb (here, `forage` and `rest`).